# Control Raspberry Pi 3 through bluetooth connection

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth, uart, serial-console

I have a raspberry Pi3 with bluetooth connection to my MAC computer.

I need to control raspberry from MAC using bluetooth like serial interface (uart)

Is there any way to do that? I only see using raspberry to control other.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: The easiest way would be to use HC-05 connected to the UART GPIO pins. But as you have a Pi 3 with built in bluetooth, I agree that this is a sub optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to do something similar and while I can't fully answer your question, I can only share a few things that I have found helpful. When you say control your PI from your mac I'm assuming sending some command from the mac to get the PI do something. In which case you will need to write a script of some description that will take the input received via bluetooth from your mac and use that to trigger some function. I'm not sure you can run Xming or something like that through bluetooth but perhaps someone else could clarify that. 
I found the information here:

https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2016/02/cheap-bluetooth-buttons-and-linux/

quite useful.

The python code using evdev package from:

https://gist.github.com/jburgess777/a6dd67e7fbaaee82c856

makes this process quite easy to capture bluetooth events. Thanks to JBurgess777 to sharing this. When connected this code captures key stroke events. What I do then is parse the output of evdev.ecodes.EV_KEY: for the particular key code and use that to trigger the action that I am trying to trigger. Hope that helps get you started.